Django rest framework Google OAuth best packages
I am currently building a webapp with backend in django and frontend in react (Later, I want to add mobile app for it too. I want to add login via Google as only option, so it would be easier for users to register/login. What packages do you think will work the best? What will be the easiest to implement?
